# How to read public/private key files for encryption when they are Base64?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I'm trying to learn RSA public/private key-pair encryption in Java.

I have the code below working.  It generates a private & public key pair, writes the keys to disk, encrypts the string with the public key from disk, the decrypts with the private key from disk, and then it outputs the decrypted string.

All works great.

The next thing is, I want the key files to be the readable "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" type of key files ... so I wrote the method `saveKeysToDiskBase64`.

The problem is, when I write the files using `saveKeysToDiskBase64`, the methods that read the key files fail.  That is `loadPrivateKey` and `loadPublicKey` can't read the Base64 files.

What am I missing?

```
public class EncryptionTest1 {


    public void execute() throws Exception {
        
        String filename = "test1";
        
        KeyPair keyPair = EncryptionUtil.generateKeyPair();
        EncryptionUtil.saveKeysToDisk(filename, keyPair);
        // EncryptionUtil.saveKeysToDiskBase64(filename, keyPair);

        String pvtKeyFilename = filename+".key";
        String pubKeyFilename = filename+".pub";
        
        PrivateKey privateKey = EncryptionUtil.loadPrivateKey(pvtKeyFilename);
        byte[] bPrivateKey = privateKey.getEncoded();

        PublicKey publicKey = EncryptionUtil.loadPublicKey(pubKeyFilename);
        byte[] bPublicKey = publicKey.getEncoded();

        String sOriginal = "hi this is plain text";

        byte[] encryptedData = EncryptionUtil.encrypt(bPublicKey, sOriginal.getBytes());
        byte[] decryptedData = EncryptionUtil.decrypt(bPrivateKey, encryptedData);
        
        String sEncrypted = new String(encryptedData);
        String sDecrypted = new String(decryptedData);
        
        System.out.println("sOriginal = "+sOriginal);
        System.out.println("sEncrypted = "+sEncrypted);
        System.out.println("sDecryptedData = "+sDecrypted);

    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new EncryptionTest1().execute();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

...

```
public class EncryptionUtil {

    
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";

    
    public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {

        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");

        // 2048 is keysize
        keyGen.initialize(2048, random);

        KeyPair generateKeyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        
        return generateKeyPair;
    }
    
    public static void saveKeysToDisk(String name, KeyPair keyPair) {
        try {
            String privateFileName = name+".key";
            FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(privateFileName);
            out1.write(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
            out1.close();
             
            String publicFileName = name+".pub";
            FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(publicFileName);
            out2.write(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
            out2.close();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void saveKeysToDiskBase64(String name, KeyPair keyPair) {
        try {

            Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
             
            String privateFileName = name+".key";
            Writer out = new FileWriter(privateFileName);
            out.write("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n");
            out.write(encoder.encodeToString(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
            out.write("\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n");
            out.close();            

            String publicFileName = name+".pub";
            Writer out2 = new FileWriter(publicFileName);
            out2.write("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
            out2.write(encoder.encodeToString(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()));
            out2.write("\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
            out2.close();           

        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
    public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(String keyFile) {
        PrivateKey pvt = null;
        try {
            /* Read all bytes from the private key file */
            Path path = Paths.get(keyFile);
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);

            /* Generate private key. */
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            pvt = kf.generatePrivate(ks);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return pvt;
    }
    
    public static PublicKey loadPublicKey(String keyFile) {
        PublicKey pub = null;
        try {
            /* Read all the public key bytes */
            Path path = Paths.get(keyFile);
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            
            /* Generate public key. */
            X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            pub = kf.generatePublic(ks);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pub;
    }
    
    
    
    


    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] publicKey, byte[] inputData) throws Exception {

        PublicKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM).generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputData);

        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] privateKey, byte[] inputData) throws Exception {

        PrivateKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM).generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputData);

        return decryptedBytes;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: When you save the keys to disk you add header and footer lines and base64 encode the contents. But when you read them back in you fail to reverse any of it. You must remove the header and footer lines you added and base64-*decode* the contents and then supply those bytes to the appropriate KeySpec. Also, the header/footer lines you use imply a very specific format. Java's `getEncode()` method does not return that format, so those header lines are misleading. But it doesn't matter as far as your code is concerned since your load methods simply discard the header/footer lines.

Comment: Thank you Mr President!  I'll try your instructions right away and report back.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks for your help!  I got it working and posted an answer with the solution code in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great thanks to @President James K. Polk who gave me the correct answer in a comment.

Here is the Base64 related code that that worked for me ...

```
private static String PRIVATE_HEADER = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
private static String PRIVATE_FOOTER = "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
private static String PUBLIC_HEADER = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
private static String PUBLIC_FOOTER = "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";


public static void saveKeysToDiskBase64(String name, KeyPair keyPair) {
    try {

        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
         
        String privateFileName = name+".key";
        Writer out = new FileWriter(privateFileName);
        out.write(PRIVATE_HEADER);
        out.write(encoder.encodeToString(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
        out.write(PRIVATE_FOOTER);
        out.close();            

        String publicFileName = name+".pub";
        Writer out2 = new FileWriter(publicFileName);
        out2.write(PUBLIC_HEADER);
        out2.write(encoder.encodeToString(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()));
        out2.write(PUBLIC_FOOTER);
        out2.close();           

    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKeyBase64(String keyFile) {
    PrivateKey pvt = null;
    try {
        /* Read all bytes from the private key file */
        Path path = Paths.get(keyFile);
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        String s = new String(bytes);
        s = s.replace(PRIVATE_HEADER, "");
        s = s.replace(PRIVATE_FOOTER, "");
        
        bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s.getBytes());

        /* Generate private key. */
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        pvt = kf.generatePrivate(ks);
    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return pvt;
}

public static PublicKey loadPublicKeyBase64(String keyFile) {
    PublicKey pub = null;
    try {
        /* Read all the public key bytes */
        Path path = Paths.get(keyFile);
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        
        String s = new String(bytes);
        s = s.replace(PUBLIC_HEADER, "");
        s = s.replace(PUBLIC_FOOTER, "");
        
        bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s.getBytes());
        
        /* Generate public key. */
        X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        pub = kf.generatePublic(ks);
    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pub;
}
```

Comment: As James stipulated, your header and footer lines are incorrect. To make them valid, simply remove the "RSA" part out of it (i.e. `PUBLIC KEY` instead of `RSA PUBLIC KEY`). Reason: Java returns `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` binary encoding rather than PKCS#1. `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` already specifies that the key is RSA in the binary format, so it requires a different **PEM encoding** than PKCS#1, which you are currently using. Currently you are not compatible with the PEM specs / OpenSSL.

Comment: And note that Bouncy Castle libs have a PEM encoder / decoder build in.

Comment: In particular see [rfc7468 section 10 and 13](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7468#section-10): the data Java crypto returns is a PKCS8-unencrypted privatekey whose correct label is 'PRIVATE KEY' or an X.509/PKIX SubjectPublicKeyInfo whose correct label is 'PUBLIC KEY'.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes To be clear ... with "RSA" removed from header and footer, and I now "compatible with the PEM specs / OpenSSL" or do I need to make other changes?  (Bear with me, still learning!)

Comment: Um, I think you need to set the line size to the PEM specifications. PEM is based on email which had a max line size. Most libraries will handle single line public keys fine I suppose, but I'd rather make sure. This should be an option of the base 64 encoder in `java.util` that you seem to be using.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks again, I'm learning a lot today.

Comment: Well, as you are learning: I always replace `e.printStackTrace()` with `throw new RuntimeException("Exception not handled yet", e);` in my IDE. That way you don't need to initialize to `null` and your return statement can happily live within the try / catch code block. I normally prefix it with a `// TODO` comment just to be sure.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks again for the help ... I should say that this code is very much a little experiment.  I would never have printStackTrace() and rampant NullPointer threats in production code, but thanks for keeping me on my toes!